# Retaining variable values in another activity class

Tags: android, inheritance, global-variables, navigation-drawer, getter-setter

In Android, I need to send variable values from one activity class to another. I know that I can do it using intent. But, when there are lots of variable values to send through several activity class, it becomes confusing especially when I need to change only a few of them when moving from one activity class to next.

So, I have been considering to decide to maintain a central superclass of variable values that get stored permanently and they can be updated from the subclasses whenever I want. Navigation Drawer serves as an excellent candidate for superclass for this purpose since all my Android activity classes inherit from it.

```
public class ProductList extends NavigationDrawer
{
    ...
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        super.setTestVariable(9);
        ...
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(ProductList.this, ProductDetail.class);
        startActivity(intent1);
        finish();
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Now why doesn't this class retain the variable value but instead resets to 0? Anyone has any idea how to make it work?

```
public class ProductDetail extends NavigationDrawer
{
    ...
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        Toast.makeText(Context.this, "Test Variable: " + Integer.toString(super.getTestVariable()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Let us assume that Navigation Drawer acts as a superclass that acts as a central storage for all variable values and all my Android activity classes inherit from it. All activity classes update global variable values as a central storage in Navigation Drawer class only.

```
public class NavigationDrawer extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener
{
    ...
    int testVariable;

    public int getTestVariable() {
        return testVariable;
    }

    public void setTestVariable(int testVariable) {
        this.testVariable = testVariable;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: your not in same instance of NavigationDrawer

Answer (score 0):

Your testVariable is not static, it belongs to the instance of your activity, so it's normal that it is reset when you move to an other activity.
Passing variable to other activity using Intent is the appropriate way to share variables values between activities.

What you could do though, is build your app around a main application instance:

```
import android.app.Application;

public class YourOwnApplication extends Application {
    //...
    int testVariable;

    public int getTestVariable() {
        return testVariable;
    }

    public void setTestVariable(int testVariable) {
        this.testVariable = testVariable;
    }
}
```

And declare your application class in your manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.you.yourapp">

    <application
        android:name=".YourOwnApplication"
```

You can then access the variable and set its value from your activities:

```
int testVar = ((YourOwnApplication )getApplicationContext()).getTestVariable()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can deal with that use case very easily by using viewModel and MutableLiveData. 
You create a data class object and have an instance of it in your viewModel. You update its value from your activities and get that data in another activity observing that mutableLiveData object.